# what it is the meaning of '$=' in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed, special-characters

what does it mean '$=' in this script?

```
if [-f $1]
nblines=$(($(sed -n '$=' $1)))
```

I did research about `'$='` about I found nothing.

Thank you

Comment: total number of lines/buffer. it's like `wc -l`

Comment: the `=` sets the line number in a given buffer/line. the `$` means the last line/buffer. and that is `sed` nothing to do with the shell.

Comment: fwiw, google search on `sed "$="`: [this](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) and [this](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/do_it_with_sed.txt)

Comment: what's the point of the `$(( ))` around it? Why not just `nblines=$(sed -n '$=' $1)`?

Comment: I miss LMGTFY, lol...

Comment: @Paul, in case the file is empty, the arithmetic expansion will ensure the value `0` is saved in the variable, instead of an empty string.

Comment: @houda, the first line is wrong: see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1035

Comment: I do not understand how the duplicates explain what `$=` means in this particular script.